# Main tags lose colors when editing a closed post

Tags: bug, tags, design

I have just realized that a special meta-tag and moderator-only tags ([support](/questions/tagged/support), [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), etc.) lose their colour when editing **closed** questions only. They look like:

> [image]

When editing and, when looking at the post:

> [image]

This, doesn't happen with unclosed posts; when seeing:

> [image]

And when editing:

> [image]

Why is this?

Comment: Can you please add your OS and browser (w/ version)? I can't reproduce this in Firefox 65 or Chrome 71.

Comment: So you're on Windows 10 then (I'm on Windows 7). That's not usually directly related but sometimes can be. I'll try on Windows 10 and report back.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this in Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) (or Version 72.0.3626.96 (Official Build) (64-bit)) or Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0 using Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Perhaps it's related to not having access to close/reopen votes?

Comment: For me, this question is [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Comment: No repro for me. What site are you testing on? I only have >2000 rep on metaSE so I tested there but I guess you're testing on metaSO, which I unfortunately can't do with my not-quite-there-yet 1951 rep :(

Comment: @NickA I don't think so. The screenshot was taken from a question of mine that was closed and since I have >250 reputation, I have access to votes. This has been also reproduced in a random closed question.

Comment: @U9-Forward if this couldn't be reproduced, then it would not receive 8 upvotes. I think I [should blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: @double-beep You can view them, you can't cast them (although Clonkex not being able to repro may ruin that theory)

Comment: @NickA that's incorrect. I can also cast them. `250 rep: Cast close and reopen vote on your own questions`.

Comment: @double-beep *"**on your own questions**"*, I mean on all questions

Comment: is it because you're editing the tags in the original, and not the second?

Comment: @double-beep I was not able to repro on Win10.

Comment: @NickA I have similar rep levels to double-beep and cannot repro (Win 10, Chrome 72)